# Save image function not working using PIL library for resizing image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How to solve this problem? I used Pycharm IDE run my program and no errors displayed.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

size = (500, 550)
path = r"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\autoimage\view"
for f in os.listdir(path):
    print(f)
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        i = Image.open(f)
        fn, ftext = os.path.splitext(f)
        i.thumbnail(size)
        i.save(r'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\autoimage\cropped\{}_300{}'.format(fn, ftext))
```

Comment: can you post some output off this code

Comment: The filenames `os.listdir()` returns aren't full paths, so it seems like you need to be using something like `i = image.open(os.path.join(path, f))`. Alternatively you could instead use `glob.glob()` which does return full paths.